# Making a anticheat and need to check address for changes

Tags: c#, memory

So hello! I'm making an anti-cheat and have a code checking for changes and when a change comes it runs this code...

```
VAMemory vam = new VAMemory("PROGRAM SECRET YA NOW xd");

IntPtr ad = 264A373E7C0;
```

The problem is the address it's not working. ^
It doesn't like it as an `IntPtr`.

```
vam.WriteByte(ad, (Byte)100);
```

Comment: From the [`visual-studio`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-studio/info) tag's wiki: "Use this tag if you have a specific question about Visual Studio features and functionality. DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio. Consider tagging the exact technology area your question links to and also tagging a more specific version of Visual Studio. Please mention your exact VS version, edition, and update level in your question."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. If you want to write a hex value in code, you need to prefix it with `0x` so that it looks like this: `0x264A373E7C0L`. The L at the end signifies that it should be a `long`.
2. `IntPtr` doesn't implement any *implicit* cast operators, so you have to either use its constructor, or use the one of the explicit cast operators.

Constructor:

```
IntPtr ad = new IntPtr(0x264A373E7C0L);
```

Explicit cast:

```
IntPtr ad = (IntPtr)0x264A373E7C0L;
```

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PUnaEN)

Comment: Well, I tried this but got the message: "System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

Comment: How would I do then? :L

Comment: Please try now.

Comment: What do you mean try now? I have already tried it a lot of times.

Comment: Well, I'd accidentally missed off the `L` at the end, and then I edited it and then I said "please try now". And it _does_ work. See [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PUnaEN).

Comment: I found the issue it's in 
    vam.WriteByte(ad, (Byte)100);
The "ad" is too long. Is there anyway to shorten a address?

Comment: Please post a new question about that, as it's a separate issue to this, and I'm afraid I know nothing of VAM.